# Use sample weight in multi-label classification

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

When I'm working on a classification problem in scikit-learn using a linear SVM, I can apply custom weights to each training sample like so:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier

X = [[0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0]]
y = [0, 1]
sample_weight = [1.0, 0.5]
clf = SGDClassifier(loss="hinge")
clf.fit(X, y, sample_weight=sample_weight)
```

Now when I have a multi-label classification task, I need to transform the labels and the `SGDClassifier` has to be wrapped in a meta-estimator like the `OneVsRestClassifier`:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier

X = [[0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 0.0]]
y = [[0], [1], [0, 1]]
y_mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer().fit_transform(y)
sample_weight = [1.0, 0.5, 0.8]
clf = OneVsRestClassifier(SGDClassifier(loss="hinge"))
clf.fit(X, y_mlb)   # unable to pass `sample_weight`
```

However, the `OneVsRestClassifier` does not allow me to pass any parameters to the `fit` method besides `X` and `y`, therefore I am unable to apply the sample weights, like I did before. How can I apply my own sample weights in this scenario?

Comment: I tried to solve this issue with a hack: Replace the `fit` method of the `SGDClassifier`'s instance with a custom implementation that gets a reference to my list of sample weights, *but*: Turns out that `OneVsRestClassifier` clones the estimator. Not with standard python tools, of course, but by instantiating a new estimator of the same class using the parameters retrieved from the `get_params` method. Therefore the monkey-patch is not preserved and I'm back to square one...

Comment: So now I could subclass `SGDClassifier`, add the sample weights as instance parameter, patch the `get_params` method and patch the `fit` method to use the sample weights stored in the class... this is horrible 

Answer (score 3):

Instead try subclassing OneVsRestClassifier to change the fit method to allow passing the sample_weight.
You would need to change the fit() and _fit_binary() method used inside it.

Try editing the [source from here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/multiclass.py#L275) to something like:

```
import warnings
import numpy as np
from sklearn.externals.joblib import Parallel, delayed
from sklearn.base import clone
from sklearn.multiclass import _ConstantPredictor, OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer, MultiLabelBinarizer
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier

def _fit_binary_new(estimator, X, y, sample_weight, classes=None):
    unique_y = np.unique(y)
    if len(unique_y) == 1:
        if classes is not None:
            if y[0] == -1:
                c = 0
            else:
                c = y[0]
            warnings.warn("Label %s is present in all training examples." %
                          str(classes[c]))
        estimator = _ConstantPredictor().fit(X, unique_y)
    else:
        estimator = clone(estimator)

        # Only this changed
        estimator.fit(X, y, sample_weight=sample_weight)
    return estimator

class OneVsRestClassifierNew(OneVsRestClassifier):

    def fit(self, X, y, sample_weight=None):
        self.label_binarizer_ = LabelBinarizer(sparse_output=True)
        Y = self.label_binarizer_.fit_transform(y)
        Y = Y.tocsc()
        self.classes_ = self.label_binarizer_.classes_
        columns = (col.toarray().ravel() for col in Y.T)
        self.estimators_ = Parallel(n_jobs=self.n_jobs)(delayed(_fit_binary_new)(
            self.estimator, X, column, sample_weight, classes=[
                "not %s" % self.label_binarizer_.classes_[i],
                self.label_binarizer_.classes_[i]])
            for i, column in enumerate(columns))

        return self


X = [[0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 0.0]]
y = [[0], [1], [0, 1]]
y_mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer().fit_transform(y)
sample_weight = [1.0, 0.5, 0.8]
clf = OneVsRestClassifierNew(SGDClassifier(loss="hinge"))
clf.fit(X, y_mlb, sample_weight=sample_weight)

clf.predict(X)
# Output: array([[1, 0],
#                [0, 1],
#                [1, 1]])
```

Note: This will work only with those classifiers which have defined sample_weight in their fit() methods, because I dont check for the presence in `_fit_binary_new()`.

Comment: This seems to work, but I can see how it's going to blow up as soon as the sklearn-devs decide to touch one of these functions. Maybe I should file a bug report (or a feature request) for this. Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Klamann Maybe because OneVsRestClassifier is designed to work with all estimators which dont have sample_weight in their fit(). Anyways I tried searching for existing issues for this request, but could not find one. Feel free to add that. Also, please accept the answer if it worked and helped.

Comment: I've submitted a [feature request](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/10882) for this. I see how OneVsRestClassifier should be able to work with other estimators as well, so the obvious solution would be to pass arbitrary kwargs to the underlying estimator. I'm gonna leave this open for a while, maybe someone will come up with a less intrusive workaround.